# Get only unique matches using lookahead

Tags: regex

I have some debug output from compiler (gcc) listing all include directories it used:

```
......... /usr/include/boost/serialization/traits.hpp
....... /usr/include/boost/serialization/split_member.hpp
....... /usr/include/boost/serialization/base_object.hpp
........ /usr/include/boost/serialization/force_include.hpp
........ /usr/include/boost/serialization/void_cast_fwd.hpp
....... /usr/include/boost/serialization/wrapper.hpp
```

It's over 3000 lines, all of which look kind of like this. I would like to get a list of dependencies loaded, but of course, one per path. Something like:

```
/usr/include/boost/
/usr/local/include/log4cplus/
```

So far I made this: https://regex101.com/r/gM3aW4/1

```
\.+\s((?:\/[a-z]+)+)\/(include|lib)\/([a-z0-9\+]+)
```

It properly matches and provides you with paths, but lists them repetitively. I've seen somebody using lookahead expressions `(?! ... )` on this. I tried "putting" `\1-3` references into lookahead to prevent matching path that can be matched later but I allways either get all paths or non.

I understand lookahead is slow, but performance is not a matter since I'll run this regex manually once in a long time.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to pass your output through a |sort|uniq pipe?

Comment: @LajosVeres It would be fastest if I ran through the file manually with paper and pencil. I'm asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to get only unique matches:

```
\.+\s((?:\/[a-z]+)+\/(?:include|lib)\/[a-z0-9_+-]+)(?![\s\S]*\1)
```

Here `(?![\s\S]*\1)` is a negative lookahead to ensure matched group # 1 doesn't exist in the rest of the input. `[\s\S]` matches any char including newlines.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM3aW4/2)

Comment: Ok... I tried a similar thing but regex101 failed with timeout error. I guess I'll try to match it in terminal console.

Comment: I have provided you a regex101 link also where it is showing only unique matches.

Comment: That's because you didn't paste 3000 lines into it. Let me just test it in terminal and accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: This kind of pattern will crash with more or less items.