# WebWorker calculates slow regexp matches significantly slower (3x) - firefox only

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, web-worker

First I just created myself a regular expression that will match all unique external library paths in a list of all header files in a project. [I asked a question regarding making that regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32841562/607407) a week ago.

I started meddling around to see how it would behave when asynchronous and when turned into a web worker. For convenience and reliability I created this universal file that runs in all three modes:

```
/** Will call result() callback with every match it founds. Asynchronous unless called 
 *  with interval = -1.
 *  Javadoc style comment for Arnold Rimmer and other Java programmers:
 *  
 * @param regex regular expression to match in string
 * @param string guess what
 * @param result callback function that accepts one parameter, string match
 * @param done callback on finish, has no parameters
 * @param interval delay (not actual interval) between finding matches. If -1, 
 *        function  will be blocking
 * @property working false if loop isn't running, otherwise contains timeout ID
 *           for use with clearTimeout
 * @property done copy of done parameter
 * @throws heavy boulders
**/
function processRegex(regex, string, result, done, interval) {
  var m;
  //Please tell me interpreter optimizes this
  interval = typeof interval!='number'?1:interval;
  //And this
  processRegex.done = done;
  while ((m = regex.exec(string))) {
    Array.prototype.splice.call(m,0,1);
    var path = m.join("");
    //It's good to keep in mind that result() slows down the process
    result(path);
    if (interval>=0) {
      processRegex.working = setTimeout(processRegex, 
                              interval, regex, string, 
                              result, done, interval);
      // Comment these out for maximum speed
      processRegex.progress = regex.lastIndex/string.length;
      console.log("Progress: "+Math.round(processRegex.progress*100)+"%");
      return;
    }
  }

  processRegex.working = false;
  processRegex.done = null;
  if (typeof done=="function")
    done();
}
processRegex.working = false;
```

I created a test file, rather than pasting it here I uploaded it on very reliable web hosting: [Demo](http://u8.8u.cz/testing/workers/) - [Test data](http://u8.8u.cz/testing/workers/dependencies.txt).

What I find very surprising is that there is such a significant difference between web worker and browser execution of RegExp. The results I got:

- Mozilla Firefox

  - `[WORKER]: Time elapsed:16.860s`
  - `[WORKER-SYNC]: Time elapsed:16.739s`
  - `[TIMEOUT]: Time elapsed:5.186s`
  - `[LOOP]: Time elapsed:5.028s`

You can also see that with my particular regular expression, the difference between a synchronous and an asynchronous loop is insignificant. I tried to use a match list instead of a lookahead expression and the results changed a lot. Here are the changes to the old function:

```
function processRegexUnique(regex, string, result, done, interval) {
  var matchList = arguments[5]||[];
  ... same as before ...
  while ((m = regex.exec(string))) {
    ... same as before ...
    if (matchList.indexOf(path)==-1) {
      result(path);
      matchList.push(path);
    }
    if (interval>=0) {
      processRegex.working = setTimeout(processRegex, interval, 
                               regex, string, result, 
                               done, interval, matchList);
      ... same as before ...
    }
  }
  ... same as before ...
}
```

And the results:

- Mozilla Firefox

  - `[WORKER]: Time elapsed:0.062s`
  - `[WORKER-SYNC]: Time elapsed:0.023s`
  - `[TIMEOUT]: Time elapsed:12.250s` (note to self: it's getting weirder every minute)
  - `[LOOP]: Time elapsed:0.006s`

Can anyone explain such a difference in speed?

Comment: If you’ve filed a Firefox bug for this, can you please add the bug URL to your question? And if you’ve not yet filed a Firefox bug for it, I hope you can please consider taking time to do that.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I googled where to report firefox bugs and I failed. So I filled complaint "*Can't find where to report bugs*" on firefox input ("*Firefox made me sad.*") and gave up. If you know where to report bugs (and it's actual report procedure, not some sink for user feedback), please tell me. This wouldn't be the first time I found problem I could reliably reproduce and identify as firefox-only.

Comment: Yeah agreed they don’t make it as clear as it could be. Anyway, for this particular bug, please use https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=DOM%3A%20Workers&format=__default__ That will raise it against the appropriate `DOM: Workers` bugzilla component in the appropriate bugzilla `Core` product.

Comment: By the way, in general for bugs you find in the core browser-engine behavior in Firefox (as opposed to bugs in the Firefox user interface or whatever), the way you want to report them is to go to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&format=__default__ and scroll through the **Component** select box there, and from that, choose the most-specific component that you can find to report the bug against.

Comment: To try help other people avoid the same frustrations you ran into with trying to figure out where to report Firefox browser-engine bugs, I  created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059442/how-as-a-programmer-to-report-bugs-i-find-in-core-gecko-browser-engine-behavio If you think it’s useful to have that info on record here in StackOverflow, please consider upvoting it (otherwise it may be at risk of getting deleted if other kneejerk close-all-the-things downvoters jump on the bandwagon).

Comment: Firefox takes a long time because it seems to 'pause' after finding `/usr/include/net/`, before finding `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/`, although that does seem to match the source location, but not THAT much. It finds `/usr/include/net/` in 1.5s, then pauses 10s, then finds the rest in 1.5s. Maybe it trips on the white space?

Comment: I see the same 'pause' in Chrome, but MUCH shorter.

Comment: Hi, I thought I'd link you to this, https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/209, in case it is relevant. I've seen slow regex handling in Firefox before, but I can't remember testing for differences in speed between browser-thread and web-worker-thread execution.

Comment: @Rudie the point is that no such "pause" happens when the execution is im main thread. Otherwise I just think that pause happens because there's lot of non-matching text at that moment.

Comment: This may not be the subject of the question, but the pattern is slow. Regex101 has a debugger, but not for JavaScript. If you switch to PCRE, you get a timeout. I optimized (?) the pattern to [`^\.+\s([\/a-z]+?\/(?:include|lib)\/[a-z0-9_+-]+)(?![a-z0-9_+-])(?![\s\S]+?^\.+\s\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/gM3aW4/3), and it still takes 218091 steps. With more lines, it will take much longer...

Comment: Also, I think you have a bug - if you have something like `... /usr/include/features`, `... /mobile/usr/include/features`, the first line will not match - my version fixes that.

Comment: The pattern is slow on purpose. Much more efficient way to do is to skip the lookaheads and use refference array instead. But this question really isn't about writing optimal code.

Comment: I think this is simply a matter of the firefox js engine not being built to optimize crazy corner cases of the language - what you have written here is truly non-production friendly code and close to as far from optimal use of the language as i have seen in the 20+ years i have worked with javascript.

Comment: @MartinJespersen That doesn't explain the performance difference. Also the code itself is not the cause of the slow speed. Please investigate the issue before saying unwise things. Several people already posted similar comments (and even one answer) and all is deleted now, because it's not relevant. Your emotions regarding the code are not interesting to anyone.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato: it is actually relevant, but i see that you are not interested in that particular relevance, so i will let you continue on your wild goose chase, good luck

Comment: @MartinJespersen You're expected to prove whatever you say. My sample code proves beyond doubt that the problem is in the way regex is compiled, not the way the rest of the code looks like. If you can write a sample code where the same regular expression runs fast in code that you personally like, I will gladly apologize for thinking that you're just another ignorant flamer. But for that you need actions, not words.

Comment: ... and to you and anyone else who comes here to discuss coding style of test snippets, by **relevant** I mean **rigorously explains what causes the problem**. None of the self-titled coding masters who tried to say that the problem is related to coding was able to prove that, at least theoretically. If anyone else wants to start a discussion on that topic, be specific. If you have no proof, you better not even start about that.

Comment: Please post your note as an answer and then accept it. This will remove this question from the "unanswered" queue. I can do it via a community post, but I think you deserve any additional points you earn from answer votes.

Comment: @JDB I will try to keep the asnwer up-to-date with the bug. Frankly I hoped someone will figure that's the cause and post better answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a series of tests, I confirmed that this is a **Mozilla Firefox** issue (it affects all windows desktop versions I tried). With Google Chrome, Opera, or even Firefox mobile, the regexp matches take about the same, worker or not.

If you need this issue fixed, be sure to vote on [bug report on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1213676). I will try to add additional information if anything changes.