# Possible reasons for different SRI results in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, subresource-integrity

A client would like to use SRI on all CSS and JS assets on their website, but they ran into a very strange issue with Firefox. Their server is an apache2 instance, serving HTML content. CORS is enabled for the whole virtual host, for any (`*`) origin. There is no cache or CDN in place.

The two files in question are

- `company.min.css` and
- `company.min.js`

To generate the SRI hashes, initially [SRI Hash Generator](https://report-uri.io/home/sri_hash) was used. The output from this has multiple algorithms and looks like this:

```
<script src="https://example.com/static/company.min.js" integrity="sha256-aKuSpMxn15zqbFa0u0FVA7mAFOSVwIwU4gA3U7AZf5Y= sha384-WDAg+qGBjbEyE52SdQ5UHdTObTY+jYTL63m9Oy2IJcGZR8AFn0t9JNN7qdut6DBk sha512-bxmUFj1FVOVV74+zIYau/HSUcLq9cuneBKoMJyW9dAz//yKFi8eRhyyIezF++2vbGO7cR6Pzm1l9rvnPcrvIrg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

similar for the CSS file. These were inserted in the HTML and the site was tested in a few different browsers, with these result:

- **works** in Chrome (/Canary), Opera, Edge and even IE
- **doesn't** work in Firefox (/Nightly).

Firefox only dislikes the CSS, saying that the SHA512 does not match the resource. It processes the JS file fine for whatever reason.

I confirmed (using OpenSSL) that the hash generated by the above tools is indeed correct, and the fact that it works in almost every browser except Firefox got me thinking.

So I tried to hash the resources using Mozilla's own SRI tool, [srihash.org](https://www.srihash.org/), which is a recommendation by Mozilla from their [blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/) on SRI.

Now it get's a bit weird.

- For the CSS file, srihash.org generates a *completely* different hash.
- For the JS file, the hash is the same for both generators and match my offline hashing with OpenSSL.

*But*, if I replace the CSS link with the Mozilla-generated one, this is the result:

- **works** in Firefox
- **doesn't** work *anywhere* else, since the hash mismatches

**Question**

I *suspect* this is some problem within Firefox' SRI implementation. The relevant discussion for the implementation is [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992096), but it doesn't give any reasons why the resource is different in Firefox. But I'm not strictly a web developer, so are there any likely (documented) reasons for different SRI hashes in different browsers?

<sub>I can't disclose the exact server/resources. This is a general question, so if you have any objective experience or references to authorized sources documenting differences in the SRI implementation, please answer.</sub>

Comment: I will add to the CC list in that bug, it's really interesting why mozilla have done this task different than other browsers. I think it's because some kind of freedom behavioured, as usual, but it's better a consense. Good luck!

Comment: Can it be connected to encoding or mime-type of your css? May be firefox interprets your css in different way than other browsers do and that's why it has another hash?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Firefox. You should consider taking time to [report this as a bug in the Mozilla bugzilla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059442/how-as-a-programmer-to-report-bugs-i-find-in-core-gecko-browser-engine-behavio/33059443#33059443). Use https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=DOM%3A%20Security&format=__default__ to get to the right component.

Comment: @sideshowbarker It already is reported and is being worked on.

Comment: @mınxomaτ URL for the bug?

Comment: @sideshowbarker [1271796](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271796); depends on [1269241](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269241).