# What is a script from source 'undefined' mean in CSP?

Tags: javascript, firefox, stripe-payments, content-security-policy, lastpass

I have recently moved from stripe.js v2 to stripe.js v3 / elements. As part of this, I am recieving new CSP errors. These don't seem to be causing stripe to fail, but I would like to understand them:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src"). Source: ;undefined.
elements-inner-card-15fb9df8718486f330c3990dde96bfd7.html:1

Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src"). Source: ;undefined.
controller-3984d4085075df939703ec0d22159407.html:1
```

Both `elements-inner-card-15fb9df8718486f330c3990dde96bfd7.html` and `controller-3984d4085075df939703ec0d22159407.html` are from stripe. What I don't understand is the `script-src` of `undefined`?

- How can a `script-src` be `undefined`? A `<script>` element generally had a `src` , if not it's `unsafe-inline`. What does `undefined` mean?
- How can I modify my CSP to allow Stripe v3?

**Edit**: the error only seems to occur on Firefox, when using LastPass. Chrome does not show this error, nor does Firefox with Addons Disabled.

Comment: That looks like a bug in Firefox that you should consider reporting. (For some tips on reporting Firefox, see the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059442/how-as-a-programmer-to-report-bugs-i-find-in-core-gecko-browser-engine-behavio/33059443#33059443).

Comment: @sideshowbarker Good point. Looks like the error happens everywhere, even on Stripe elements demo site, so filed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1458200

Comment: I’ve seen similar errors caused by browser add-ons and the like. Try restarting Firefox without add-ons and see if the error still happens

Answer (score 1):

For those ending up here like me, the solution was different than "disabling addons".

Context: I'm using stripe in React and I use [react-stripe-elements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-elements) to do it.
The CSP error came when I was doing this:

```
<form>
    {loading ? <Spinner /> : <CardElement /> }
</form>
```

It seems that the dynamic mounting/unmounting does not go well there.
I changed it like that:

```
<form>
    <div className={classnames({hidden: !loading})}><Spinner /></div>
    <div className={classnames({hidden: loading})}><CardElement /></div>
</form>
```

With the corresponding CSS for `hidden` of course and the error went away.

Hope it helps some lost souls :)